# UITapGestureRecognizer Returns Wrong Cell IndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, uipopovercontroller, custom-cell

I am adding a UITapGestureRecognizer in my cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I do this so that on an iPad, I can present a UIPopoverController from the place the table view was touched.  In each custom cell, I have a button called commentButton.  This is the thing that can be touched.  The app uses Parse and each row is an entry from a PFObject.  The table view loads fine, but when clicking, it returns the wrong object.  I click the first item, and it returns the object from the 3rd row.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    self.theObject = object;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(getpoint:)];
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.commentButton addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
    [tapped release];
//other code below this point was removed as not relevant
}

-(void) getpoint: (id)senderButton
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) senderButton;
    gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    self.thePoint = [gesture locationInView: [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] view ]];
    [self thisisit];

}

-(void)thisisit {
    Mail *mail = [[Mail alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Afterclicked cell %@", self.theObject);
    NSString *html = self.theObject[@"Request"];
    NSString *thetitle = [self.theObject[@"Title"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSString *thedate = self.theObject[@"dateMade"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM_dd_yyyy"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *theNewDate1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:thedate];
    NSString *theNewDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:theNewDate1];

    mail.thehtml = html;
    self.nameofhtmlfile = [[[[@"http://www.iprayed4u.net/app/" stringByAppendingString:thetitle] stringByAppendingString:@"_"] stringByAppendingString:theNewDate] stringByAppendingString:@".html"];
    //  Reminder *thereminder = [[Reminder alloc] init];
    //thereminder.thehtml = html;
    //thereminder.thetitle = thetitle;
    //thereminder.thedate = thedate;

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self] applicationActivities:@[mail]];


    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,

                                              UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,

                                              UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                              UIActivityTypeMail,
                                              UIActivityTypePrint

                                              ];

    }
    else {

        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,

                                              UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,

                                              UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                              UIActivityTypeMail,
                                              UIActivityTypePrint,
                                              UIActivityTypeAirDrop
                                              ];

    }

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
        [aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.thePoint.x, self.thePoint.y - 150, 300, 300) inView:[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] view ]permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
    else {
    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

    }







}
```

Comment: Why do you need to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a button? Doesn't a button kind of do this anyway? If you do this, you really won't need to determine where the tap is happening. Additionally, perhaps you could find the locationInView: for the tableView. I suspect you're referencing the wrong view. Can you explore what view `[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] view ]` is?

Comment: I have it there to get the point in the view of the app that it was touched.  that view is the main root controller view.  It works just fine, it gives me the CGPoint touched, and I display the popover controller exactly at that point.  The issue is that it is not giving me the correct object, but rather the last object on the screen.

Comment: Yeah, you're using `self.theObject` which is going to be the object of the last cell that is rendered. There is only 1 `self.theObject`. You should query the data model once you've gotten the touch point. This is most likely your issue.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out below.

Answer (score 0):

You have the reusable cells here.

This messes everything up, because this way one cell can be reused in many places.

Try to always create cells in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** without using reusable cells.

Be careful - this affects performance a little. If this is a problem you can go deeper into details and leave reusables intact fixing the problems behind it. (hint: cells **are** reusable, but the gesture recognizer is not)

Comment: I really need to use reusable cells for performance.  I think the issue is that the gesture recognizer is initialized in cellforrow and not didSelect, and so when that happens, the self.theObject is set as whatever the final returned value was, versus the selected cell.  I tried setting this all up in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but it didn't register anything in that code method when I clicked on commentButton.  How can I go about having didSelect recognize that I'm clicking that area and perform something different than when clicked elsewhere?

Comment: You can use simple buttons and their selectors. Set the .tag property on the button to be equal to row index. This way when button is touched a method is called and inside that method you can see which row was selected. (sender.tag)

Comment: Also, try to put your gesture recognizer initialization code inside the if (cell==nil) {} where you create your cells (in cellForRow:)

Comment: I cannot get it to call anything at all in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  The cell has a property commentButton, but nothing happens when that part is pushed if all code is in didSelect

Comment: Do not use DidSelect in your case!

Comment: DidSelect is used to detect table row selection.
Use the action method your button is set to.
(get rid of gesture recognizer - you don't need it here)

Comment: Without gesture recognizer, how can I get the CGPoint of the location in the overall view where the user tapped?

Comment: We are getting confused here. You should either use buttons or gesture recognizer. (sorry for misleading you)
They both suit your case, but buttons are simpler. You can get location by seeing button's frame.origin property. 
The original problem is with reusable cells. If you consider leaving gesture recognizer - put it inside the IF (cell==nil) {} as I suggested.

Comment: i figured out the problem. I have in my cell implementation the code for when button is pressed. From there, it sets what would be the correct object to pass on. But in the cellForRow section, I also have the object set so I can use the title from object for a label in cell. The code in cell gets called first and passes the correct ovject, but then is overwritten by the other incorrect object.